# Get button focus - MFC

Tags: mfc, button, dialog, focus

I have a VC++ MFC dialog application and in my OnTimer function I am just trying to determine which button in my dialog currently has focus.

Here is some pseudocode of what I am trying to accomplish....

```
CDialog::OnTimer()
{
     CButton *btn = GetButtonOnFocus(); 
     int btnID = btn->GetDlgCtrlID();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but this should work:

```
CWnd * pFocus = GetFocus();
int btnID = 0;
if (pFocus != NULL && pDialog->IsChild(pFocus))
    btnID = pFocus->GetDlgCtrlID();
```

This won't restrict the result to buttons only - to do that, you need to use GetClassName and compare to "button".

Comment: I've tried the same, it works but the button press works if I click outside the button area (i.e. the button remains focused). Any suggestions on how do I kill focus when I move out of its region?

Comment: @TheNewbie, I'm not sure what you're asking here. You might have better luck by opening a new question and adding some detail on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Adrian, that would work too if you're only querying a single button and you have the `hwnd` handy. The question specifically asks "which button" so I think my answer is closer to what was needed.